# Measuring runtime with counter variable

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, runtime, big-o

I am currently working on an assignment which asks us to implement a few different sorts and introduce counter variables to measure the runtime.

My question is that I'm confused about whether or not to include certain "operations" as something that would increment my counter. For instance, my textbook says this:

[image]
    ....

So, from what I understand, I should be counting "comparisons" but I do not understand if this applies to if statements, while loops, etc.

For instance, here is my insertion sort.

```
float insertionSort(int theArray[], int n) {
    float count = 0;

    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; unsorted++) {
        int nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;

        while ((loc > 0) && (theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)) {
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            theArray[loc] = nextItem;
            loc--;
            count += 4;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

As you can see, I increment count by 4 for each iteration of the while loop. This really highlights my question, I think.

My reasoning is that we make two comparisons in the conditional statement of the while loop:

(loc > 0 && theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)

Afterwards, we make two moves in the array. From my understanding, this means that we have performed 4 "operations" and we would increment counter by 4 for the sake of measuring runtime at the end of execution.

Is this correct? Thank you SO much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your number of exchanges is proportional to your number of comparisons. Also, your `loc > 0` is what I'd consider an "incidental operation" as stated in that excerpt. So, assuming comparisons and movements are constant time operations (which they are for integers), you'll get the same trends in your data by simply incrementing your counter once each loop iteration.

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure how I did not realize that they just act like constants since they are present in every iteration. Thanks a lot, that was some good insight.